# kCFRunLoopCommonModes error with SwiftUI Toggle

Tags: runtime-error, toggle, ios13, xcode11

The following code shows an iOS 13 SwiftUI Toggle example. It runs on a device (iPhone XR), but shows an error in the log when the toggle is tapped. I only observe this on a device, not the live preview.

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var foo = false

    var body: some View {
        Form{
            Toggle(isOn: $foo, label: {
                Text("Label")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The error is:
**2019-09-23 12:59:01.468146-0500 Demo[640:40285] invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.**

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: It happens without SwiftUI as well. Looks like it's a bug somewhere in the UISwitch code (using Xcode 11).

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs for me with a toggle on the iPhone 8 simulator.

No crash experienced.

The cells having the toggles would not properly resize when moved, but this was avoided by adding a Bool and toggling it as part of the cell move function { eg, triggerRefresh.toggle() }  This unexpected user behavior may or may not be related to the toggle error.

Comment: You can you elaborate on this answer? I'm not sure how to implement this fix?

Answer (score 0):

Same as C K,
No crash experienced.

I got the value of the switch using a separate Bool var

```
var stateOfSwitch = false
```

And used a separate @IBAction for the switch like so..

```
@IBAction func toggled(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    stateOfSwitch = ! stateOfSwitch
}
```

Remember to link the IBAction to the switch element in your interface builder.

And use the stateOfSwitch variable to implement any logic you have to implement based on the switch.

I am aware this is a work around, hoping this won't be needed soon.

Not sure how to do this in SwiftUI.

Comment: Never had this problem with UIKit.